# Add a number to all rows. SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

suppose I want to add a $2500 bonus to all income column. How to achieve it?e.g.

```
Old table:
id name     salary
1  John     8000
2  Labron   5000
3  Elvis    6000

New table:
id name     salary  SalaryWithBonus
1  John     8000    10500
2  Labron   5000    7500
3  Elvis    6000    8500
```

Do I have to use PL/SQL function for this? I'm new in this field so please don't get annoyed if the question is kind of silly type.

Comment: THis is oracle? Please tag as such.  You want to add a new column to the table, not clear?

Comment: yes I want to add a new column with the added value

Comment: 2 statements: 1) alter table to add the new column and 2) an update to fill it.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing the result of the calculation. You should store the salary and the bonus in two columns. Then _calculate_ `salarywithbonus` when you retrieve the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the other way to do this. Have a table called BONUS with a YEAR column.
You could also store the bonus per month.

```
    CREATE TABLE OLD_TABLE
(ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR2(12), SALARY DECIMAL(18,2));

INSERT INTO OLD_TABLE values(1,'John',8000);
INSERT INTO OLD_TABLE values(2,'Labron',5000);
INSERT INTO OLD_TABLE values(3,'Elvis',6000);
INSERT INTO OLD_TABLE values(4,'Elvis2',NULL);

Create Table BONUS
(YEAR NUMBER, BONUS_AMT DECIMAL(18,2));

insert into BONUS VALUES('2016','2500');
insert into BONUS VALUES('2017','2500');

SELECT Id, Name, Salary, (NVL(salary,0) + BONUS_AMT) SalaryWithBonus FROM OLD_TABLE CROSS JOIN BONUS WHERE BONUS.YEAR = 2017
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me to explore a new concept to do that

Answer (score 1):

To add the column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD SalaryWithBonus DECIMAL(12,2);
```

To fill the fields:

```
UPDATE
    table_name
SET
   SalaryWithBonus = salary + 2500;
```

With the great comment below, if the salary is `NULL` you have two options.

1. Treat `NULL` as 0
2. Do not set a bonus salary for  those with a `NULL` salary.

Option 1:

```
UPDATE
    table_name
SET
   SalaryWithBonus = COALESCE(salary,0) + 2500;
```

Option 2:

```
UPDATE
    table_name
SET
   SalaryWithBonus = salary + 2500
WHERE 
    salary IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Though may need to coalesce salary if null to be 0 so the 2500 can be added.  `coalesce(salary,0)+2500`  edge case stuff.  And not so sure about `int` in a salary field.  `decimal(12,2)` or something seems better.  not too many people make more than 9 billion a year right?  maybe

Comment: True, INT may not be the best example, especially with salaries that (in the real world) often include cents. Your 2 cents were definitely helpful!

Comment: It would be better to store **only** the bonus. `salarywithbonus` can easily be calculated from the two columns then.

Comment: Bonus!  Salary + $2500.02 for me  (be sure to case my $.02 in) :P  So much crap to consider when putting this stuff together. Often we're so much in a haste to get the work done we fail to consider the implications of our actions.  Int for a currency field, varchar for numeric, varchar for date... float for currency...  I need help storing Avagadro's constant.  (ok I'll let you use float this time) before it's too late!

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name points out, you can do this without adding the ``salarywithbonus`` column to the table.